# How can I get a sha1 of an entire ref in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, sha1

I would like to compare two copies of parts of a ref to see if they have changed. How can I get a sha1 of a map and any sub leaves?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on exactly what you want to do, you may find just using the normal Java hashCode() via the "hash" function is simpler than trying to use SHA:

```
(hash {:a "hoho" :b "hehe"})
=> 2025831869

(hash {:a "hoho" :b "hihi"})
=> 2025836181
```

This is enough in most cases to determine if two maps are different.

Note that neither SHA or any other hashcode guarantee equality when two objects have the same hash - many objects can potentially have the same hash. As a consequence, if the hash is the same you will still have to check whether the two objects are equal in value

Also, be aware that computing hashes is *more expensive* than a simple comparison using =. So it only makes sense to use a hashing technique if you are able to store the hash value and re-use it for many comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure you actually want something as low-level as that? Identity in clojure, at least wrt values, is kinda built in:

```
user> (= {:a 1, :b {:c 2}} (hash-map :b {:c 2} :a 1))
true
```

Comment: good point. But how computationally expensive is it to use =  (I have to do alot of comparing)

Comment: IIRC, the Clojure data structures cache the hash code and perform a comparison based on the hashes first, so it should be fast in most cases.

Comment: So since hash is not unique does this mean that it is possible for a Clojure = on two different hash tables to incorrectly return "true" ?

Comment: It's the other way around: if the hash isn't the same, the value isn't (or shouldn't) be the same. = should still test the actual values for objects that have the same hashes (and there are ways of speeding up cases like symbol comparisons for example) but because you can eliminate the much more common unequal cases, that generally turns out to still be pretty good, performance wise. by the way, this also means you want your hash function to be FAST, rather than particularly strong ~ making SHA1 not the best candidate for generic objects.